# $A_4 \oplus Z_3$ has no subgroup of order 18

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here my solution: Suppose there exists and $H \leq A_4 \oplus Z_3$ such that order of H is 18. Now, notice index of H in $A_4 \oplus Z_3$ is 2. therefore, H is normal, and therefore, the $A_4 \oplus Z_3 / H$ exists. Now, for every $\alpha$ in $A_4 \oplus Z_3$, $\alpha^2H = (\alpha H)^2 = H$ since the quotient group has order 2. But notice, $A_4$ has only 3 elements of order 2, therefore, $A_4 \oplus Z_3$ have only 3 elements of order 2, which implies H has 3 elements of order 2 and the rest must have order 1, and this is an absurd.

Is this a correct solution? Do you guys have any other solution?

thanks,

Comment: CORRECTION: A4⊕Z3 have only 3 elements of order 2, which implies H has 3 elements of order 2

Comment: Why does that imply H has 3 elements of order 2?

Comment: since every $\alpha$ is in H

Comment: Why is every element of order $2$ contained in $H$?

Comment: for every α in A4⊕Z3, $α^2H=(αH)^2=H$

Comment: Which implies $\alpha^2\in H$ for every $\alpha\in A_4\oplus Z_3$, but how do we get $\alpha\in H$?

Comment: we dont need $\alpha$ in H, since $\alpha^2$ is in H for every $\alpha$ in $A_4 \oplus Z_3$

Comment: I repeat: I'm asking you how we should know the $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^2=e$ are contained in $H$. How do we know this?

Comment: BY LAGRANGE THEOREM. one of its corollaries say order of an element divides order of a group

Comment: How does that corollary imply the elements of $A_4\oplus Z_3$ of order $2$ are contained in the subgroup $H$?

Comment: I see, $A_4 \oplus Z_3$ have an element of order 5. no good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image of $H$ under the projection $A_4\oplus \mathbf Z_3\to A_4$ would be a subgroup of $A_4$ isomorphic to $H/(H\cap \mathbf Z_3)$, which is of order $18/\#( H\cap \mathbf Z_3)$. But $A_4$ neither has any subgroup of order $18$ (obviously) nor of order $6$ (requires only slightly more reflection).

Comment: sorry for bringing up a dead post, but why would the image of $H$ be isomorphic to $H/(H \cap Z_3)$?

Comment: @pinklemonade By the first isomorphism theorem, since $\mathbf Z_3$ is the kernel of the projection, and therefore $H\cap\mathbf Z_3$ is the kernel of its restriction to $H$.

Answer (score 2):

The group $G=A4 |+| Z3$ has not a subgroup of 18 order

Proof:

Let $H$ be such a group. Then as the order of $G$ is equal to $12 \cdot 3=36$ index of $H$ is equal to
$\frac{36}{18}=2$ so $H$-normal. Therefore $G/H$ of order $2$ exists. If $g$ from $G$ then $(g^2)H=(gH)^2=H$,
So the square of any element from $G$ belongs to $H$. But in A4 there are 9 different elements
of the form $a^2$ and in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ all three elements are of this form. Then in $G$ in all $9 \cdot 3=27>18$
such elements. CONTRADICTION. The theorem is proved.

Answer (score 1):

The normality observation is a good starting point, but I do not follow the reasoning where you take it.

Hint: try to deduce that $H\cap A_4$ would have to be an index-2 subgroup of $A_4$ (of which there are none). You can apply one of the isomorphism theorems to help do this.

Comment: I havent yet learned the isomorphism thms :(

Comment: One of them says that in a parent group $G$, take $A$ and $B$ to be subgroups, with $B$ normal. Then $(AB)/B\cong A/(A\cap B)$. Apply this with $A=A_4$ and $B=H$. You will have to think about the possibilities for what $AB$ might be. There are two cases: one of which is ruled an impossibility by my hint, and the other is ruled an impossibility by $H$'s index and $A_4$'s index.

Answer (score -1):

$\operatorname{Order}(g1+g2)=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{Order}(g1),\operatorname{Order}(g2))$.

But for any $g_1$ from $A_4$, $\operatorname{Order}(g_1)\leq4$ and for any $g_2$ from $Z_3$, $\operatorname{Order}(g_2)\leq3$.

So, $\operatorname{Order}(g_1+g_2)\leq12$.

Comment: H is subgroup of G=G1XG2 if and only if H=H1XH2, where H1,H2-subgroups of G1 and G2. So max(|H|)<=max(|H1|)max(|H2|) But max(|H1|)=4,max(|H2|)=3