# $\mathbf{A_4}\oplus\mathbf{Z_3}$ has no subgroup of order $18$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that:

$\mathbf{A_4}\oplus\mathbf{Z_3}$ has no subgroup of order $18$

$|\mathbf{A_4}\oplus\mathbf{Z_3}|=36$ so subgroup $\mathbf{H}$ has index $2$  and must be normal.

Thus the quotient group
$\frac{\mathbf{A_4}\oplus\mathbf{Z_3}}{H}$ exsists and has only two elements.

Now if $\alpha\in\mathbf{A_4}\oplus\mathbf{Z_3}$ then
${\alpha}^2\mathbf{H}={(\alpha\mathbf{H})}^2=\mathbf{H}$

Thus ${\alpha}^2\in \mathbf{H}$

How can I now show there more than $18$ elements for which ${\alpha}^2$ doesnot belong to H

I know there are six elements of order $2$ in 
$\mathbf{A_4}\oplus\mathbf{Z_3}$.

THANKS.

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208269/a-4-oplus-z-3-has-no-subgroup-of-order-18