# Show that $A_4 \times Z_3$ does not have a subgroup of order 18

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

I see that the exact same question has been asked:[$A_4 \oplus Z_3$ has no subgroup of order 18](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208269/a-4-oplus-z-3-has-no-subgroup-of-order-18) but I don't really understand the accepted answer. Why is it that the image of $H$ in the projection $A_4 \times Z_3 \to A_4$ would be isomorphic to $H/(H \cap Z_3)$?

Is there also possibly another way to prove this?

Comment: Because the kernel of the projection is $1\times Z_3$. So $H(1\times Z_3)/(1\times Z_3$) is isomorphic to the image of $H$ (first isomorphism theorem), and $H(1\times Z_3)/(1\times Z_3)\cong H/H\cap (1\times Z_3)$ holds by the isomorphism theorems.

Comment: In the context of "the accepted answer" to the other Question (duplicate), do you understand why $A_4$ (the alternating group of permutations) has no subgroup of order $6$?   That is also an important ingredient for the given solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an application the first isomorphism theorem:

If $\psi:A_4\times Z_3\to A_4$ is the projection, then $\ker(\psi)=Z_3$.

If we restrict this to $H$ with $\psi_H:H\to A_4$ then $\ker(\psi_H)=H\cap\ker(\psi)=H\cap Z_3$. The first isomorphism theorem gives the image of $H$ is isomorphic to $H/(H\cap Z_3)$.

An alternative solution is hinted in one of the other answers:

Write $G=A_4\times Z_3$ and note that $|G|=36$

If $|H|=18$ then $[G:H]=2$ so $[A_4:H\cap A_4]\le 2$.

If $[A_4:H\cap A_4]=1$ then $|H\cap A_4|=12\nmid 18$, so $[A_4:H\cap A_4]=2$.

So, as in the accepted solution, the problem reduces to showing $A_4$ has no subgroup of order $6$.

Comment: How can the kernel be just $Z_3$ if the input of the function is $A_4 \times Z_3$?

Comment: The kernel always is a (normal) subgroup of the group, here $A_4\times Z_3$. So this is alright. Please review again the kernel of a homomorphism.

Comment: @pinklemonade strictly speaking the kernel is $\{1\}\times Z_3$, but it is quite normal to refer to this as $Z_3$